# php array access first element return null

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to access 'Organisation, support et services' in this array, is it possible ?

var_dump result of unassociated variable :

```
array (size=2)
  'Organisation, support et services' => 
    array (size=3)
      54 => string 'Architecture d'entreprise' (length=25)
      55 => string 'Outils de collaboration et patrimoine informationnel' (length=52)
      53 => string 'Sécurité' (length=10)
  'Applications' => 
    array (size=3)
      52 => string 'Système d'information activités recherche' (length=43)
      50 => string 'Système d'information budget, finance, compta' (length=46)
      51 => string 'Système d'information ressources humaines et paie' (length=50)
```

var_dump($unassociated);

```
foreach ($unassociated as $value) {
    //var_dump($value[0]);
    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_evaluateur" name="" id="' . $key . '">' . $value . '<br/>';
    }

}
```

I tried $value[0] but i get null.

When i var_dump inside the first foreach i get :

```
array (size=3)
  52 => string 'Système d'information activités recherche' (length=43)
  50 => string 'Système d'information budget, finance, compta' (length=46)
  51 => string 'Système d'information ressources humaines et paie' (length=50)
```

i would like to get 'Applications' wish is just before this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check the key of the current array on `foreach`:

```
foreach ($unassociated as $key => $value) {
        //var_dump($value[0]);
    if ($key == 'Applications') {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_evaluateur" name="" id="' . $key2 . '">' . $value2 . '<br/>';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving same `$value` name while looping child loop.

```
foreach ($unassociated as $key => $value) {
    //var_dump($value[0]);
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_evaluateur" name="" id="' . $key1 . '">' . $value1 . '<br/>';
    }

}
```